# How to properly use ListView in AppWidget using Kotlin or Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-widget, remoteview

My goal is to build a scrollable home screen widget. I'm trying to use Kotlin, but Java solutions are welcome too. Every documentation I found online was either outdated or did not include scrolling. `ScrollView` does not seem to be supported, so I tried to use a `ListView`. As far as I know you can only add content to `ListView`s programmatically. I tried

```
class NewAppWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }
}

internal fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int) {
    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.new_app_widget)
    views.addView(R.id.listView, RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.new_app_widget_list))
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
}
```

but my widget always looks like this:
[image: "problem loading widget"]

Comment: You should use a recyclerView and not listView as listView has memory issues

Answer (score -1):

You should check offical documents.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets#collections

You dont have to add programmatically.Add listview to layout from xml and set it with

remoteviews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.yourlistview, intent)

Further information is available in upper link.